# Async await paradigms applied to a remote controller application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am writing a remote controller application in c#.

In particular i have a server that receives and simulate events.

And a client that listen mouse/keyboard events and send it to the server.

My problem is that i don't want that the GUI thread write directly to the socket .
Because it can leads to a block of the GUI, so i choose to use the await/async paradigm for avoid that.

In particular i have modified my write method in this way.

```
public static async void  write_on_server_socket(ServerApp s, String str)
        {

            try
            {
                Stream stm = s.tcpServer.GetStream();
                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);

                await stm.WriteAsync(ba, 0, ba.Length);

                return 0;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Now my question are:
1) First of all, it solve my problem?
2) It can cause an wrong order of arrive of messages to the server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are never disposing of the stream. change the first line to `using(Stream stm = s.TcpServer.GetStream())`. Also your catch is causing you to loose your stack trace, either do `throw;` with no `ex` or get rid of the try/catch entirely. Lastly You have `async void` that should ***ONLY*** be done if your method is a event handler, is `write_on_server_socket` a event handler?

Comment: Your exception handler isn't handling anything.  In fact, it's throwing away useful information about the exception.  Better to just remove it entirely and let the exception continue up the stack.  To that end, you'll want to use `async Task` instead of `async void` so that the consuming code can examine the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI will not be blocked by this. In that sense it solves your problem.

Be aware that `async void` has some problems. Usually, you'd return a `Task` so that calling code can find out when this write is actually complete. And that might well be a problem: You might have multiple concurrent writes and the order that data arrives in is not guaranteed. Be sure to have only one `WriteAsync` operation outstanding at any time.

Comment: How can i be sure about that?

Comment: WriteAsync guarantees that it does not block. await handles the marshalling on and off of the UI thread. await is made for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `async Task` instead of `async void`.

> 1) First of all, it solve my problem?

Have you tried it?

Hint: yes, `await` will not block the GUI thread.

> 2) It can cause an wrong order of arrive of messages to the server?

No.

Comment: 1)Yes i have tried it but it difficult to demonstrate it.
Also before the introduction of async await it was working.



2) why xd?

Comment: I assume by "why xd?" you mean "why not?". It's because TCP/IP preserves the order of the bytes written to the stream.

Comment: Yeah sure, but how can i be sure that the write on the stream will finish in the correct order?